# Programmatically call Keycloak silent check-sso angular

Tags: angular, keycloak, single-sign-on, openid-connect, keycloak-angular

Is it possible to programmatically fire the Keycloak silent check-sso, without a route change / page reload.

I have an application that requires the user be logged out on any interaction, rather than waiting for an interaction that triggers the silent check.